# Setindex for named tuple

Tags: julia, namedtuple

I am trying to write a non-mutating `setindex` for named tuple, where given a value  type for the name `var`, it creates a new named tuple where `x.var = y`. What I have right now is:

```
function setindex(nt::T,x,v::Val{var}) where {T,var}
  if var ∉ fieldnames(T)
    return x
  else
    typeof(x)(s == var ? y : w for (s,w) in nt)
  end
end
```

but my main issue is that I'm not sure of a good way to iterate the named tuple to get the `(name,value)` pairs.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the number of parameters in your function correct? What purpose does `x` serve if you already have `nt` (eg. `function setindex(x::T, y, v::Val{var})`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the `@generated` version. The generated code is dead simple and type stable.

```
julia> @generated function setindex(x::NamedTuple,y,v::Val)
         k = first(v.parameters)
         k ∉ x.names ? :x : :( (x..., $k=y) )
       end

julia> @code_warntype setindex((a=2, b=3), 4, Val(:b))
Body::NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}}
2 1 ─ %1 = (Base.getfield)(x, :a)::Int64                                                               │╻╷╷   macro expansion
  │   %2 = %new(NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}}, %1, y)::NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}}│┃││╷  merge
  └──      return %2                                                                                   ││    

julia> @code_warntype setindex((a=2, b=3), 4, Val(:c))
Body::NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}}
2 1 ─     return x
```

Comment: `nt = (a=2,b=5); (nt..., b=4)`. Wow, I never new that worked. That makes it a lot simpler! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pairs` which gives an iterator for key-value pairs, or use `fieldnames` with type `T` and access the value with `nt[name]` or (use `keys` with the named tuple variable the same way). I think you prefer `pairs`.

```
function setindex(nt::T,y,v::Val{var}) where {T,var}
  if var ∉ fieldnames(T)
    return nt
  else
    T(s == var ? y : w for (s,w) in pairs(nt))
  end
end
```

or

```
function setindex(nt::T,y,v::Val{var}) where {T,var}
  if var ∉ fieldnames(T)
    return nt
  else
    T(k == var ? y : nt[k] for k in fieldnames(T))
  end
end
```

Comment: The only problem with this implementation is that it is not type stable. I think using a `@generated` function here could be a better solution in some cases or at least to add a `::T` type annotation to return value of a function, which would cover type instability.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Why is it so? How would specifying return type solve it? It already has to return T in both branches of `if`.

Comment: Try calling `@code_warntype` on your code on a named tuple `(a=1, b="2", c='3', d=nothing)` and you will see that there is a problem. If you have 4 or more unique types in the `NamedTuple` Julia will fail to provide correct types (this limit is "in built" AFAIK to improve performance of the compiler).

Comment: As a side note - I had the same problem when implementing ABMs in Julia. See https://juliasnippets.blogspot.com/2018/07/abc-of-abm-in-julia.html section **Several types of agents** and also https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28583 (I have not checked if with `NamedTuple` the reason is also `tmerge` as in the issue, but it most likely is the same problem).